# Bash script somehow calling files in my directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that goes through a CSV and gets users that have a last login date of over 2 months ago. I found an algorithm online to help compare dates from the current date.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

#while read user updateDate lastLoginDate
 #do
        #echo $user

 #done < jira.csv
 currentDate=$(date +%F)
 echo $currentDate
 IFS=$OLDIFS

year=$(echo $currentDate| cut -d'-' -f 1)
month=$(echo $currentDate| cut -d'-' -f 2)
day=$(echo $currentDate| cut -d'-' -f 3)

calculateDaysPassed () {
        daysCalculated=365 * $year + $year / 4 - $year / 100 + $year / 400 + [ $month * 306 + 5] / 10 + [ $day - 1 ]
}

calculateDaysPassed # "$year" "$month" "$day"
echo $daysCalculated
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error like this which gets a file in my directory.

```
parseJiraUsers.sh: line 24: Atom.app: command not found
```

So the Atom app is in my desktop directory (same as where this script and the CSV I'm using is). I moved it to my Documents and it just throws another command error at a document I have there. Wtf is going on?

FYI: This worked with the CSV parts above non-commented out. I just commented them out to see if anything changed (It didn't).

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks dude! It helped me figure out why my arithmetic was wrong. Thanks so much!

Comment: `IFS=- read year month day <<< "$(date +%F)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do math like that.  The source of that weird error is your use of * for multiplication in this line:

```
daysCalculated=365 * $year + $year / 4 - $year / 100 + $year / 400 + [ $month * 306 + 5] / 10 + [ $day - 1 ]
```

The way this is being interpreted, you are setting `dayscalculated` to 365. After that, everything else on that line is like a separate command.  So first, it will interpret * to be all the files in the current directory.  It will try to execute the first file name as if it were a command, and the rest of the line will be treated as arguments to that command.  Hence, the command `Atom.app`...

You should use the `$((...))` to do this c-style math, however, this only works with integers.  Your results may not come out the way you want because of all the division.  You may need to use a tool like `bc`.

Comment: You might show `daysCalculated=$(( ... ))` to be showing how to do this right, not just what the mistake was.

Comment: Ha. Same second.

Comment: (also, it's `(`, not `)`, for grouping in *either* native shell arithmetic or `bc`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Cyrus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678568/bash-script-somehow-calling-files-in-my-directory/51678965#comment90320351_51678568) suggesting shellcheck.net.

That site pointed out that I was doing my arithmetic wrong by not putting `$(())` around `daysCalculated`.

Fixing this addressed my problem.

Comment: Do provide the code fix, for other peoples later on, or close your question.